# !== и || в условии

Tags: javascript

Как можно изменить это условие, чтобы в консоль не выводилось `3`?

```js
const a = "1";

if (a !== "1" || a !== "2") {
  console.log(3);
}
```

При этом не вынося `console.log(3)` за пределы  `if () {}`.

---

```
if (user.role !== 'overlord' || user.role !== 'admin' || user.role !== 'moderator') {
  return Promise.reject(config.get('msgs.typeErrors.smallRole'));
}
```

"Если роль пользователя не оверлорд, или не админ, или не модератор, то ..."

Comment: @AlTheOne, - Как можно изменить это условие, чтобы в консоль не выводилось 3? - вопрос и состоит в изменении условия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а чего вы ожидаете от условия **ИЛИ**?

в вашем случае условие **ВСЕГДА** срабатывает

ну сделайте

```js
const a = "1";

if (a !== "1" && a !== "2") {
  console.log(3);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуй, мне стоило добавить контекст, пожалуйста, пересмотрите мой вопрос, я его изменил

Comment: @Voprositel, приведённое вами условие опять будет всегда выполняться!!! вы же опять ИЛИ используете при использовании НЕ - ИЛИ НЕ А ИЛИ НЕ Б - это значит ВСЕ!!!